# What does "paid to look the part" mean?

Tags: phrases

As in:

> ... admit they're not monks but
>   employees paid to look the part.

(from NGM March 2011, p. 101)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are professional actors collecting a fee for playing the role of a monk, thus not genuine.

Comment: Ah yes. [look the part = to look suitable for a particular situation](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+the+part) . Got it, thanks `:)`